# Prove that the alternating group has a subgroup of order 12

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that $A_{5}$ has a subgroup of order $12$.

What I have so far:
The order of an alternating subgroup $A_{n}$ = $n!/2$. So the order of $A_{5}$ is $60$. We know that the order of a subgroup must be divide the order of the group, and this is the case since $12$ divides $60$.

Also, I have another question. Are all alternating groups cyclic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the Alternating group $A_{4}$, it has order 12, and it's in $A_{5}$. Aletnaring group $A_{n}$ is  not cyclic for $n >3$

Comment: Why is $A_{4}$ a subgroup of $A_{5}$? Is it always the case that a smaller alternating group will be a subgroup of a larger alternating group?

Comment: Never mind, someone else answered this question.

Answer (score 4):

Are alternating groups cyclic?  Well, all cyclic groups are abelian (you should prove this).  Is the alternating group abelian?

As a hint to your subgroup of order $12$ question, note that $A_n \subset A_m$ for all $n < m$.